# Using JSColor on the Edit page. .NET Core

Tags: c#, html

I'm using JsColor for Background Color and Font Color in a .NET Form. This is a general MVC scaffolding template. The "Create" page works perfectly, and I'm able to choose colors using JsColor. The problem is with the "Edit" page, I'm able to edit all of the data except for the background color and font color - since they are using JsColor. What's happening is that when I choose a color using the plugin, it immediately switches back to the original color selected on the "Create" form.

I believe this is because I'm using C# to display database information.

The Javascript for this plugin is 1,000+ pages long but I will copy and paste sections if necessary.

Edit Page

```
             <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BackgroundColor" class="control-label">Background Color</label>
                <input asp-for="BackgroundColor" class="form-control jscolor {width:243, height:150, position:'right',
                    borderColor:'#FFF', insetColor:'#FFF', backgroundColor:'#666'}" />
                <span asp-validation-for="BackgroundColor" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FontColor" class="control-label">Font Color</label>
                <input asp-for="FontColor" class="form-control jscolor {width:243, height:150, position:'right',
                    borderColor:'#FFF', insetColor:'#FFF', backgroundColor:'#666'}" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FontColor" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

Index Table

```
           <td bgcolor="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BackgroundColor)">
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FontColor)">
```